# How to makesomething available in visual studio code's intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

Lets say I have an object like this:

```
const test = {
  ab: '12',
  de: '34',
  fg: '11',
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to make this object available in intellisense? So that I can just type ctrl+space and can access it like `test.[show me possible values]`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are looking for some type helpers, you can either chose typescript or flow (Two very popular).

Typescript (I prefer this) works just like javascript but it has types (compiles to js).

Flow just adds types to existing js files with extra syntax. (has to be compiled with babel to produce runable js).

Then if you would write this in .ts file, vs code would already tell you what properties exist on const `test`.

After that you can take it up a notch and declare type for `test` variable and it will even check if you are not trying to assign some random stuff to it, which could break other stuff.

Comment: can u please guide me how to declare a type for this, so I can access it anywhere in my typescript based project.

Comment: @coure2011 well if you write it in ts file, you should be able use it straight away, if you refer to it in same file, your IDE should offer your its values. if you want to use it in different file, do `export const test = ...` and import it in the other one, like `import {test} from "..."`  and then you should be able to use it in that file aswel

Comment: any way to put in intellisense without importing?

Comment: @coure2011 well you cant use it, could you tell me the use case and I will try to help you as much as possible, but you cant have intelisense, if you cant call the thing you want the intelissense on

Comment: I have some translation file in json (vuei18 plugin) I want to access it from everywhere. Once I have typed the correct key I will just wrap it in qoutes..